# How to tar a file that is opened and under concurrent writes by another process?

Tags: tar

For example, while an application continuously writes text lines to a file named `./data.csv`, i ran the following tar command:

```
tar cvfz /tmp/1.tgz ./data.csv
```

Though tar did create the tar ball `/tmp/1.tgz` containing a snapshot of the file `./data.csv`, it exited with code 1 and an error string "No such file or directory".

Any idea what happened to this tar operation and how to circumvent the error above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to copy the file and tar that?

Comment: @Murphy i see no error to copy the file and tar that. Problem is only with a file that is concurrently changed.